# Refresh value in text label from JSON, with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am learning Swift to develop macOS applications and I ran into a problem. I am trying to get certain data from a JSON from the internet. I have managed to get such data and put it in simple text labels in the view but when I run Xcode and get the values, if the values from the JSON get updated, I can't see it reflected in my app. I know that I must perform a function to refresh the data but what I have always found is the function to refresh the data that is in a table, not a simple text label.
Regardless of this problem, if I wanted to add a table with 3 columns (each structure has 3 data, at least) with the values from the JSON. When I run the refresh of the table, I should include in the function the function that gets the data from the internet, right? I'm a bit lost with this too.

This is what I have:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    let user_items = UserItems()
    
    @IBOutlet var item_salida: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let struc_item = user_items.Item_Struct()
        let position = struc_item.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Leanne Graham" })!
        
        print(struc_item[position].state!)
        
        item_salida.stringValue = struc_item[position].state!

    } }
```

**Struct.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

// MARK: - Dato
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var username: String?
    var email: String?
}

typealias Datos = [User]

class UserItems {

    func Item_Struct() -> Datos {
        
        let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
        var items_available: [User] = []
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString){
            if let data = try? NSData(contentsOf: url as URL, options: []){
                let items = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data as Data)
                for item in items {
                    items_available.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        return items_available
    }
}
```

Thanks, a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - as you are learning Swift - please stop using *snake_case* variable names and also the `NS..` classes `NSURL` and `NSData`.

Never load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`. It blocks the thread.

You need `URLSession` and an asynchronous completion handler.

```
// MARK: - Dato
struct User: Codable {
    let name: String
    let username: String
    let email: String
}

typealias Datos = [User]

class UserItems {

    func loadData(completion: @escaping (Datos) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do {
                let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data!)
                completion(items)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And use it in the controller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var itemSalida: NSTextField!
    
    let userItems = UserItems()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        userItems.loadData { users in               
            if let position = users.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Leanne Graham" }) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(users[position].username)
                    self.itemSalida.stringValue = users[position].username
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

And forget `SwiftyJSON`. It's not needed anymore in favor of `Codable`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the warnings and tips. Try to use the code with my url, getting the value when i run xcode, but when the url value changes, there is no change in the app window. What can happen?

Comment: You should get errors in the console. A different URL requires a different model.

Comment: It seems strange to me as the url is similar in format to the test url. Disable the firewall and the console keeps showing this message: 
`
nw_association_schedule_deactivation <nw_association 192.168.0.15:8080> will become dormant after 10 seconds of inactivity
`

Comment: Programming is a very precise subject. *Similar* means different.

Comment: I know I speak from ignorance but the viewDidLoad () function does not load only at the start of the app? Shouldn't I run the data load function elsewhere? Sorry if I said something silly.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called **once** after the controller has been instantiated.

Comment: but once it is called and executes the code (reading the json file) how does it run continuously? to update the field value

Comment: @learningswift you must know when to refresh. You can put the chunk of loading data into a separate function. Whenever you need to refresh, just call it again.